# Hamburger Menu / UserControl Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm learning creation of menu. I have some issue, maybe the same that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983245/navigation-button-dependent-on-conditions-from-other-viewmodel).

My app contains :

- one master container (MainWindow)
- one menu (MenuView)
- some views

The MainWindow is defined like this (two columns, one for the menu, the other for views):

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource PrimaryBackgroundColor}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Menu}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Application visual]

When we click on menu items, there are no displayed views (built with UserControl).

I add the following codes :

- MainWindowViewModel.cs

  ```
    #region Constructor
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Menu = new MenuViewModel();
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    private object _menu;
    public object Menu
    {
        get
        {
            return _menu;
        }
        set
        {
            _menu = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Menu));
        }
    }

    private object _selectedViewModel;
    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
        }
    }
    #endregion Properties
  ```
- MenuViewModel.cs

  ```
    #region Variable
    MainWindowViewModel mainWindowObj;
    #endregion Variable

    #region Constructor
    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        menuCommand = new RelayCommand(load_menuChoiced);
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    public ICommand menuCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion Properties

    #region Public Methods
    #endregion Public Method

    #region Private Method
    public void load_menuChoiced(object obj)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case "Home":
                mainWindowObj = new MainWindowViewModel()
                {
                    SelectedViewModel = new HomeViewModel()
                };
                break;

            case "Graphic":

                break;

            case "Setting":

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion Private Method
  ```

Could you explain me why it doesn't work and help me to fix it ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It may be that HomeView was not found, Add this code to MainWindow's Resources property.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
    <view:HomeView/>
</DataTemplate>
```